# whats wrong with this canvas movement

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Hello im trying to program the classic pong game. I am trying to implement smooth movement.So when the key has been released it should gradually slow to a stop. I have been following a few tutorials but cant seem to get it straight.

I noticed if you keep hold arrow up for a bit and let it move then hold arrow down it will still move in the up direction for a bit then start moving down. any idea whats this from?

Here is my code:

```js
var canvas;
var canvasContext;

var x = 5,
  y = 150;
var velY = 0;
var speed = 50;
var friction = 0.9;

window.onload = function() {
  canvas = document.getElementById("gameCanvas");
  canvasContext = canvas.getContext("2d");

  var fps = 30;
  setInterval(function() {
    draw();
  }, 1000 / fps); // 1000miliseconds = 1 seconds 

  document.addEventListener("keydown",
    function(event) {
      var x = event.key;

      switch (x) {
        case 'ArrowDown':
          key_down();
          velY *= friction;
          y += velY;
          break;
        case 'ArrowUp':
          key_up();
          velY *= friction;
          y += velY;
          break;
      }
    });
}

function key_up() {
  if (velY > -speed)
    velY--;
}

function key_down() {
  if (velY < speed)
    velY++;
}

function draw() {
  //canvas background color  
  colorRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height, "black");

  //left player paddle  
  colorRect(x, y, 15, 100, "white");
}

function colorRect(leftX, topY, width, height, drawColor) {
  canvasContext.fillStyle = drawColor;
  canvasContext.fillRect(leftX, topY, width, height);
}
```

```html
<canvas id="gameCanvas" width="600" height="400" style="border:1px solid black;"></canvas>
```

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, it's "Why does the rectangle not immediately" reverse direction? The answer is because you are incrementally changing velocity. If you want to immediately reverse direction, set velocity to zero when the key indicating the opposite direction is pressed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way it is programmed it will slow down its speed before moving in the other direction. If you set the velocity to 0 first, it will start moving directly.

```js
function key_up() {
  velY = 0; // Set to zero to stop paddle
  if (velY > -speed)
    velY--;
}

function key_down() {
  velY = 0; // Set to zero to stop paddle
  if (velY < speed)
    velY++;
}
```

Comment: thanks alot! just curious how i would make it look like it gradually slowing down?